# Find subarrays with first element greater than or equal to last element and the subarray size equal to X

Tags: java, arrays

Got stuck with this. I was solving some array related queries,that is when I came across this problem.
It asks me to divide an array to a size entered by the user,such that first value of the array must be greater then or equal to the last value of the array.

I cannot make out how can I create the sub-arrays.
E.g.      X = 4      A = { 0, 4, 10, 6, 15, 9, 18, 35, 40, -30, -90, 99 } 
The sub-arrays of size 4 with first element greater than equal to the last element are  {10, 6, 15, 9}, {18, 35, 40, -30}, {35, 40, -30, -90}

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for(int i =0; i < array.length-3; i ++){
 // 3 can be replaced by x-1
 if(array[i]>array [i+3]){
   System.out.println(array [i] + array [i+1] +array [i+2] +array [i+3]);
// Instead of printing you can save the sub array or do what you prefer
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class Demo {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        int A[]={0,4,10,6,15,9,18,35,40,-30,-90,99};
        int X=4;
        ArrayList<int[]> arr=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<A.length-X;i++) {
            if(A[i]>=A[i+X-1]) {
                int temp[]=new int[X];
                for(int j=0;j<X;j++) {
                    temp[j]=A[i+j];
                }
                arr.add(temp);
            }
        }
        for(int[] temp:arr) {
            for(int j=0;j<X;j++) {
                System.out.print(temp[j]+"   ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("Done....");
    }
}
```